# Laravel: matches array (Tinder clone) to my user returns empty

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a Tinder clone to practice, I want to retrieve a user matches (when both users like eachother) but when I do:

```
$user = User::with('matches')->findOrFail(1);
```

The matches array returns empty, despite all users liking eachothers,

I created a Users_Users_liked pivot table:

```
Schema::create('users_users_liked', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_liked_id')->nullable()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_liked_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I set up the User model with relationship as follows (notice matches realtionship, which always returns an empty array)

```
public function likesToUsers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'Users_Users_liked', 'user_id', 'user_liked_id');
    }

    public function likesFromUsers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'Users_Users_liked', 'user_liked_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function matches()
    {
        return $this->likesFromUsers()->whereIn('user_id', $this->likesToUsers->keyBy('id'));
    }
```

In my UsersSeeder I give likes to user 1 from all users

```
        $users = json_decode($json, true);

        foreach ($users as $data)
        {
            $user = new User();
            $user->name = $data['name'];
            $user->save();

            if($user->id > 1)
            {
                $user->likesToUsers()->attach([1]);
                $user->save();
            }

        }

        $user = User::findOrFail(1);
        $user->likesToUsers()->attach([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]);
        $user->save();
```

Comment: and what is the question? :) maybe you didnt finish asking your question

Comment: Updated OP with actual question

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues in your current `matches` relationship:

1. `whereIn` takes an array of ids (where the values of each item is the `id`), whereas, using `keyBy` will mean that the values are the instances of the model. `pluck` would have been the right method to use i.e. `$this->likesToUsers->pluck('id')`.
2. The above would only have worked if you already had the model loaded so eager loading wouldn't have worked. There are a couple of reasons for this:

   1. The models wouldn't have yet been loaded so you couldn't then call the `likesToUsers` relationship to actually retrieve the ids i.e. you can't use the **value** of one relationship in another relationship in this way.
   2. Even if you were lazily eager loading the relationships, if you were loading multiple models, Laravel would actually only use the relationship values from the first model (I think it's the first) so the rests of the relationships would be wrong.

What you can do though is use the query side of a relationship to retrieve the data. The long and the short of it is don't try and use the **value** of one relationship in another when trying to eager load.

---

All that being said, one option would potentially be to join the pivot table on the relationship (again) and compared the opposite columns:

```
public function matches()
{
    return $this->likesFromUsers()
        ->join('users_users_liked as alt_users_users_liked', function (JoinClause $join) {
            $join
                ->whereColumn('users_users_liked.user_liked_id', 'alt_users_users_liked.user_id')
                ->whereColumn('users_users_liked.user_id', 'alt_users_users_liked.user_liked_id');
        });
}
```

---

Some general notes/tips:

You can simplify your `users_users_liked` migration by using the [foreignId()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-foreignId) method instead:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
$table->foreignId('user_liked_id')->constrained('users')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
$table->timestamps();
```

It's also usually a good idea to add a unique constraint to your pivot tables (unless you potentially want duplicates):

```
$table->unique(['user_id', 'user_liked_id']);
```

Finally, it might be worth taking a look at [Model Factories](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#defining-model-factories).

Comment: Using your matches relationship I get this error: Argument 1 passed to App\\\\Models\\\\User::App\\\\Models\\\\{closure}() must be an instance of App\\\\Models\\\\JoinClause, instance of Illuminate\\\\Database\\\\Query\\\\JoinClause given, called in C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\AdoptaUnaTiaBE\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Database\\\\Query\\\\Builder.php on line 465\

Comment: @gabogabans Oh, you either need to import the `JoinClause` class or just remove the type hint.